# react-router-dom Element Type Invalid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm new to React and ES6, and am a bit stuck with `react-router-dom`. I'm currently either getting error messages or none of the information seems to be loading in. I'm using React 15.6.

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './components/App';
import Vote from './components/Vote';
import Results from './components/Results';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <App>
      <Route path="/" component={Vote} />
      <Route path="/results" component={Results} />
    </App>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

If I have the two `Route` declarations in **index.js**, I am getting an error

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a 
class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. 
You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.
```

I think this means that `this.props.children` doesn't have a value, so it can't clone the route with the pair list correctly?

If I remove the one of the `Route` declarations, the page does successfully compile, but it's just empty. I added a line of text to the `return()` in **Vote.jsx** and it does output that, so the route is working correctly, just nothing is being outputted for the `this.getPair()` function.

[image: React Page Compiled]

It looks like **App.jsx** also loads correctly, as it I change the return in this file to output text, it does so.

As mentioned, I'm entirely green to this, so I'm hoping its something fairly simple, or just a misunderstanding of how everything stitches together.

**App.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import {List, Map} from 'immutable';

const pair = List.of('Item One', 'Item Two');
const tally = Map({'Item One': 5, 'Item Two': 4});

export class App extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {pair: pair})
    )
  }
};

export default App;
```

**Vote.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

export class Vote extends React.PureComponent {

  getPair() {
    return this.props.pair || [];
  }

  isDisabled() {
    return !!this.props.hasVoted;
  }

  hasVotedFor(entry) {
    return this.props.hasVoted === entry;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="voting">
        {this.getPair().map(entry =>
          <button key={entry} onClick={() => this.props.vote(entry)} disabled={this.isDisabled()}>
            <h1>{entry}</h1>
            {this.hasVotedFor(entry) ? <div className="label">Voted</div> : null}
          </button>
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
};

export default Vote;
```

**Results.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

export class Results extends React.PureComponent {

  getPair() {
    return this.props.pair || [];

  }

  getVotes(entry) {
    if (this.props.tally && this.props.tally.has(entry)) {
      return this.props.tally.get(entry);
    }

    return 0;
  }

  render() {
   return (
      <div className="results">
        {this.getPair().map(entry =>
          <div key={entry} className="entry">
            <h1>{entry}</h1>
            <div className="voteCount">
              {this.getVotes(entry)}
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
};

export default Results;
```

Comment: are u using React 16 ?

Comment: Simple error in your first `<Route/>`'s `component` prop. Change `Vote` to `Voting`, or vice versa, to match your import statement.

Comment: @Joshua_M for future reference, anytime you see an `Element type is invalid` that means you are referencing a JSX element incorrectly. Either you have an error in your export/import statements (such as in this case) an issue with your casing (If it is not in pascal case react will throw an error) or a missing return statement in your render method

Comment: @ArmanCharan Sorry, it is `Vote` not `Voting`. I modified the code a little to make the question. I've updated the question with the correct information.

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI I am using React 15.6

Comment: Next step might be to try nesting the routes within a [`<Switch/>`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch) statement, seeing as giving the `<App/>` component one child seems to work.

Comment: Also, `getPair()` isn't bound to `this`. You might want to try calling it using an arrow function or binding it inside of your component's `constructor()` method.

Comment: You can also pass `props` directly to route components like so: `<Route path="/" component={() => <Vote pair={pair}/>} />`. It might be cleaner to declare the routes from inside of your `<App/>` component's file for the sake of passing data.

Comment: `<Switch/>` worked a treat, thank you. Unfortunately I'm still not getting any data in either page, even after binding the functions in the `constructor`.

Comment: Hey, I cracked it with the props directly in **App.jsx**, so App.jsx returns the `<Switch />` with the directly routed components. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Arman Charan**'s comment about using a `<Switch />` statement was the way that I got the routes to work and to stop receiving the mentioned error.

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
      <App>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={Vote} />
          <Route path="/results" component={Results} />
        </Switch>
    </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```